# Difference between define dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

i am developing application using C#(5.0).Net(4.5).
I want to know whats the difference between  below to declaration of dictionary variable.
1.

```
var emailtemplateValues = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"CreatorName", creatorUserInfo.UserName},
        {"ProjectName", masterProjectInfo.Title},
        {"Reason",  reason}
    };
```

and 
2.

```
var emailtemplateValues = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"CreatorName", creatorUserInfo.UserName},
        {"ProjectName", masterProjectInfo.Title},
        {"Reason",  reason}
    };
```

in 2nd declaration i have used `()` after `Dictionary<string, object>`. 
both syntax works fine but just eager to know about internal work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These two syntaxes are equivalent.  When a constructor call is omitted from the initializer expression then the compiler will attempt to bind to the parameterless constructor an that type.  This is covered in section 7.5.10.1 of the C# spec

> An object creation expression can omit the constructor argument list and enclosing parentheses provided it includes an object initializer or collection initializer. Omitting the constructor argument list and enclosing parentheses is equivalent to specifying an empty argument list.

Comment: Is there any performance difference between above two syntaxes ?

Comment: There should not be any difference. Even if, then it should be negligible. And also application perform better due to framework and design of application and these things can be ignored if you want.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation but what's the negligible performance . after all combination of negligible performance  are create a big degrade in development.

Comment: @Nilesh_Moradiya there is no perf difference between the two. They should in fact compile to the same IL

Comment: @JaredPar Ok,Appreciate sir.

Answer (score 5):

**Nothing**. When using the initializer syntax, you may omit the the parentheses. This is equivalent to invoking the parameterless constructor. They will produce exactly the same byte-code when compiled.

Answer (score 5):

No difference here, the first one is simply a [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for the second.

Answer (score 1):

There are no difference  after the processed by compiler the output is same code.